# .bat помощь с созданием выбора в меню

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, powershell

Задание такое: нужно сделать мини программку, что предложит выбрать какой файл запустить

я реализовал это через choice и Call

после выбранного файла нужно предложить выбрать о какой команде вывести на экран информацию

```
@echo off

chcp 65001

:m1
Echo.
Echo  #************************************#
Echo  * виберіть команду                   *
Echo  *------------------------------------*
Echo  * attrib        - 0                  *
Echo  * format        - 1                  *
Echo  * fdisk         - 2                  *
Echo  * exit          - y                  *
Echo  #************************************#

set /p var="Ваш вибір: "
if "%var%"=="%1" goto 1

:1
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
Echo attrib-відображення і зміна атрибутів файлів. 
Echo ATTRIB [+ R | -R] [+ A | -A] [+ S | -S] [+ H | -H] [[диск:] [шлях] їм + 
Echo Установка атрибута. - Зняття атрибута. R Атрибут "Тільки читання". 
Echo A Атрибут "Архівний". S Атрибут "Системний". 
Echo H Атрибут "Прихований". / S Обробка файлів у всіх підпапках вказаного шляху.
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
goto m1
```

сделал что то типа такого, но выводит вот такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же просьба, помочь с тем, что при нажатии команды exit не выходить с программы, а запустить опять файл под названием menu.bat что находится в той же папке, что и этот же файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Символ пайпа `|` следует квотировать при выводе с помощью команды echo. Вот так: `Echo ATTRIB [+ R ^| -R] [+ A ^| -A] [+ S ^| -S] [+ H ^| -H] [[диск:] [шлях] їм + `.

Comment: @Akina 
Если вывожу `attrib-відображення і зміна атрибутів файлів.`
все равно выдает ошибку ибо attrib нужно тоже как то экранировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вам уже подсказали, следует заменять в `echo` символ `|` на `^|`.

Также есть проблема в строке `if "%var%"=="%1" goto 1`. Вам следует сравнивать просто с цифрой, например `"0"` для вашего кода.

Чтобы вызвать menu.bat есть два варианта:

- Просто `menu.bat`. В этом случае управление перейдет на него, а текущий командный файл завершится;
- Использовать `call menu.bat`. В этом случае после завершения menu.bat управление вернется в следующую строку текущего командного файла.

Если menu.bat это основной файл, запускающий остальные, то Вам нужен первый вариант. Это позволит избежать рекурсии вызовов.

Вот полный вариант кода:

```
@echo off

chcp 65001

:m1
Echo.
Echo  #************************************#
Echo  * виберіть команду                   *
Echo  *------------------------------------*
Echo  * attrib        - 0                  *
Echo  * format        - 1                  *
Echo  * fdisk         - 2                  *
Echo  * exit          - y                  *
Echo  #************************************#

set /p var="Ваш вибір: "
if "%var%"=="0" goto 0
if "%var%"=="1" goto 1
if "%var%"=="2" goto 2
if "%var%"=="y" goto y
goto m1

:0
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
Echo attrib-відображення і зміна атрибутів файлів. 
Echo ATTRIB [+ R ^| -R] [+ A ^| -A] [+ S ^| -S] [+ H ^| -H] [[диск:] [шлях] їм + 
Echo Установка атрибута. - Зняття атрибута. R Атрибут "Тільки читання". 
Echo A Атрибут "Архівний". S Атрибут "Системний". 
Echo H Атрибут "Прихований". / S Обробка файлів у всіх підпапках вказаного шляху.
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
goto m1

:1
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
Echo format
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
goto m1

:2
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
Echo fdisk
Echo ______________________________________________________________________
goto m1

:y
menu.bat
```